# Convert character array to number

Tags: matlab

I have a character array something like this of size 2x3

```
245
234
```

I want to get a number array from this character array with values 22,43,54. How can I do this in matlab?

Comment: `str2num(input_char_array')`?

Comment: Yes, simply: `a = ['245'; '234';]; b = str2num(a.')`

Comment: Or `base2dec(a.', 10)`

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned in the comments, simply transpose your matrix first and then use `str2num`.

```
M = ['245';
'234']

str2num(M')
```

You may still want to transpose the result, but that should be manageable.